# How to select count() if there is a value but select nothing if the value is 0

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

Im writing a booking system for a project and currently working on getting some report functionality built in. I need to return a list of all classes on todays date regardless of wether they have a booking or not.

The problem i am getting is when there are no bookings, i dont get anything back from the sql query but when there are bookings, i get the correct information. If i take the count for the bookings away from the select then everything works however i need all of this info.

```sql
SELECT
    class_instances.instance_sdate,
    classes.class_name,
    classes.class_max,
    users.user_name_first,
    users.user_name_last,
    COUNT(bookings.booking_id)
FROM
    `computing-project`.class_instances class_instances,
    `computing-project`.classes classes,
    `computing-project`.users users,
    `computing-project`.bookings bookings
WHERE
    DATE(class_instances.instance_sdate) = DATE(NOW()) AND
    class_instances.class_id = classes.class_id AND
    classes.teacher_id = users.user_id AND
    bookings.instance_id = class_instances.instance_id
```

Data set : https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRBUM.jpg

This code above works only when someone has booked the class. not when the class has no booked members.

i still get the count returned as 0 but no other results for the other columns

- hope this makes sense.

Expected Output

```
+-----------------------+------------+-----------+-----------------+----------------+----------------------------+
|    instance_sdate     | class_name | class_max | user_name_first | user_name_last | count(bookings.booking_id) |
+-----------------------+------------+-----------+-----------------+----------------+----------------------------+
| 2019-03-23 16:38:00.0 | Test       |        11 | Louis           | Simpson        |                          0 |
| 2019-03-23 16:39:00.0 | Test2      |        12 | Louis           | Simpson        |                          0 |
+-----------------------+------------+-----------+-----------------+----------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Hoestly, im quite new to sql with the join syntax, do you know how i would convert this to join ?

Comment: *i still get the count returned as 0 but no other results for the other columns* What other results should there be if there are no bookings?

Comment: @Lksimo . . . You shouldn't even be learning to use commas in the `FROM` clause.  You should only learning `JOIN`.  There are many resources on and off line to learn SQL.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I realize you're new to the site so if I may I'll offer a couple of suggestions. First, your question was actually pretty good - but please don't post sample data as an image. Instead, include it in the question as text so that people can use it without having to retype everything - which most of us aren't going to do. Second, and even better, would be to go to an SQL test site such as sqlfiddle.com or dbfiddle.uk, set up your tables and populate them with data, and then people can work with it to help find a solution to your problem. Best of luck.

Comment: Thankyou @BobJarvis, Will definitely do this next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want also the not booking then you need a left join (outer) join.

You should avoid old implicit join syntax based on where, you should  use explicit join syntax and using this use left join for booking:

```
SELECT
    class_instances.instance_sdate,
    classes.class_name,
    classes.class_max,
    users.user_name_first,
    users.user_name_last,
    COUNT(bookings.booking_id)
FROM `computing-project`.class_instances class_instances
INNER JOIN  `computing-project`.classes classes ON class_instances.class_id = classes.class_id 
INNER JOIN  `computing-project`.users users ON  classes.teacher_id = users.user_id 
LEFT  JOIN  `computing-project`.bookings bookings ON bookings.instance_id = class_instances.instance_id 
WHERE  DATE(class_instances.instance_sdate) = DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY  class_instances.instance_sdate,
    classes.class_name,
    classes.class_max,
    users.user_name_first,
    users.user_name_last
```

Comment: This returned information for each of the fields when there were no bookings like i needed however it only returned one instance and there are two in the DB for today ?

Comment: I'm not in your data  ... so  update  your question  ..add  a proper (clear) data sample  . and the expected result 
 .as  tabular text

Comment: Added an image of the data set, i also got this from your query - https://imgur.com/R5sePQg Thanks for helping

Comment: Okay maybe i didnt explain well enough, im quite new to this in terms of posting on stackoverflow. Essentially i have a bunch of classes (class.instances) and i want to display all of the classes and their info that occur today. Along with that, i need to see a total of how many people are booked on the class which is calculated from the number of bookings for that instance id

Comment: Your comment and you question is not clear for expected result so  if you add  a text sample with the expected  result is better that words ..

Comment: Sorry, i see that i have explained things a little awkward, ive added my expected result, not that once a booking is made for one of the classes. the count(booking.booking_id) should increase

Comment: answer  updated .. adding the group bay for obatin the two rows  involved

Comment: Thank-you so much. This worked great, didn't like the ,1 in the count statement tho ?